# How to omit base classes in UML class diagram

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram

In an UML class diagram, how do I omit irrelevant base classes without giving a wrong impression?

Let's consider the following class hierarchy:

[image: Class hierarchy]

I want to illustrate the fact that both `Blackbird`s and `Airplane`s are `FlyingThing`s. But I don't want to clutter my UML class diagram with the entire ancestry of `Blackbird`.

I could simply leave out `Bird`, `Animal`, and `LivingOrganism`, drawing only the three "relevant" classes. But that would look as if `Blackbird` only derived from `FlyingThing` and from nothing else.

To prevent this wrong impression, I might consider including the `Bird` class after all, leaving out only `Animal` and `LivingOrganism`. But then it would look as if `Bird` had no base classes at all. Bottom line: Wherever I do the cut, it will always look as if one class had fewer base classes than it actually has.

What I'm looking for is some way to indicate that "this class has other base classes besides the ones shown, but I can't be bothered to draw them all." I imagine something along the lines of an ellipsis. Is there any standard way of expressing this?

**Edit:**

I made up the classes in this diagram to illustrate the question. So the question is *not* about whether multiple inheritance or this particular class design make sense. Let's assume they do. This question isn't about a particular UML modelling tool, either - let's assume we're working with pen and paper here.

To re-phrase my question: Imaging you saw a diagram containing just the three highlighted classes and nothing else. Would you assume that this diagram represents the whole truth and that `Blackbird` has no other base classes besides `FlyingThing`?

- If you think, yes, `Blackbird` appears to be derived from `FlyingThing` only: then there must be some standard UML syntax to indicate that this is not the case.
- If you think, no, there might be other base classes that the author of the diagram omitted: then this answers my question and I was just seeing problems where actually there are none. :-)

Comment: right :) I'll delete my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you would find a solution per designer... 
A diagram exposes a **part** of the entire model and the only a part, so the whole problem is which part? The response to this question is simply it depends of what you want to show for the understanding of your problem.

Regards,

BR

Comment: Thanks, Red Beard, for pointing out that omissions (without any special marking) are perfectly fine in a class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Red Beard rightly said, some tools give you the possibility to add hyperlinks to other diagrams (for example, enterprise architect does):

[image]

So you could add a link to another diagram that unveils the full inheritance ancestry.

But first consider this:

Does your class `Blackbird` really inherit from both `FlyingThing` and `Bird`?
Possible in some languages, but not clever design.

Or is your `generalization` to FlyingThing in fact the `implementation` of an interface? If so, you want to use the correct connection type (as indicated in the image).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is specifying the super class with its name(definition), also you would provide some note to ensure that target developer won't mixup.
example:
[image]
and by the way, I have to say, this is not belong to ISO. Coffee effects.